# Numerous separate ajax image uploads on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image-upload

I have an ajax upload script, but it only seems to work for one image upload at a time. My problem is that I am creating a shop CMS and one of the pages requires numerous image uploads, its for a product, so a product has a thumb, and 4 other images.

Normally I use this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


      var btnUpload=$('#upload');
      var status=$('#swaptd');
      $('#hideimg').hide();
      new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: 'upload-file-notes.php',
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
           if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|gif|pdf|doc)$/.test(ext))){ 
           // extension is not allowed 
                                                                              status.text('File format not supported!');
                   return false;
                                                                }
                                                                //status.text('Uploading...');
                  $('#hidebtn').hide();
                                                            $('#hideimg').show();
                    },
              onComplete: function(file, response){
              //alert(response);
              var mytext = response.split('#');
               //Add uploaded file to list
           if(mytext[0]==="success"){
                    str =mytext[1];
             newid = str.substring(0, str.length - 5);                                                                           $('#myfilename').html(mytext[1]);                                                                     document.daftform.attachments.value = mytext[1];                                                                         $('#hidebtn').show();                                                                           $('#hideimg').hide();
} else{                                                               $('#myfilename').html('error had occured');
                                                                }
                                                }
                                });

                });
```

But the problem is that if I have more than one instance of is on a page, it starts to not work correctly, Can anyone suggest how I can alter it to make it multiple upload button friendly, or another way they have done this? I am just looking for a point in the correct direction as it is becoming a problem. Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script you are using the id of your button : `var btnUpload=$('#upload');`

So you cannot use this exact script for many buttons.

You need to pass your button id as a parameter. Try to go with something this way :

- in your html tag : specify an id for each button OR `onclick="upload(this)"`
- in your javascript : change the function to have a name and receive a parameter

> function upload(button){
>        // your ajax call

```
new AjaxUpload(button, {
            action: 'upload-file-notes.php',
...
```

> }
>   }